# How to select and attribute in span tag when call window.open function

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, href

I have a span tag and I want to execute onclick function that call two window.open :

```
<span data-href="https://clkde.tradedoubler.com/click?p=300883&a=3040124&g=24628776" class="BUTTON_NZV" style="border-radius: 7px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #1BC325;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;

" onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.data-href,'_self');">OK</span>
```

The behavior I want is to open the actual page in a new tab and focus on it and open the data-href link in the previous page without focus on it! Can you help me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getAttribute` function of `this`.

```
<span data-href="https://clkde.tradedoubler.com/click?p=300883&a=3040124&g=24628776" class="BUTTON_NZV" style="border-radius: 7px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #1BC325;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;

" onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.getAttribute('data-href'),'_self');">OK</span>
```